# For $\psi$ a $C^1$ $r-1$ form over manifold, if $\phi=d\psi$, then $d\phi=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This is the proof of the following statement made in Complex Manifold and Deformation of Complex Structure Chpt 3, Sec 1 before Thm 3.2

"If $\phi,\psi$ are $C^1$ differential forms over manifold $M$ and $\phi=d\psi$, then $d\phi=0$."(Note that $\psi$ is not $C^2$ form.)

Proof: Due to locality natural, it suffices to prove $d^2\psi=0$. Say $\psi$ is $r-1$ form and $M$ is dimension $n$. Pick $\eta$ a smooth $n-r-1$ form with compact support. $\int_M d^2\psi\wedge\eta=(-1)^{2r-1}\int_M\psi\wedge d^2\eta=0$.(The first equality is true as $\eta$ is compactly supported.) Hence $d^2\psi=0$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is $d^2\psi=0$ distribution sense here as this tests over space of $C^1$ differential forms with compact support? Otherwise, I do not see how to conclude $d^2\psi=0$ from $\int_M d^2\psi\wedge\eta=0$ with $\eta$ test differential form. The reason I have trouble with the proof is the notation of $d(d\psi)$'s first differential which makes $d\psi$ as $C^0$ form but this $d\psi$ may not even differentiable.

Comment: It does seem a distributional proof indeed. If it disturbs you, I can suggest another proof, more geometric: you can show that a $\mathscr{C}^1$ $(r-1)$-form is closed iff its integral on every $(r-1)$-spheroid (aka image jn a chart of a $(r-1)$-sphere) is zero. This entails that a $\mathscr{C}^0$ limit of $\mathscr{C}^1$ closed forms that happens to be $\mathscr{C}^1$ is closed as well. Now, we can write $\psi=\lim_n{\psi_n}$ where the limit is $\mathscr{C}^1$ and the $\psi_n$ are $\mathscr{C}^2$. Then $\phi$ is the $\mathscr{C}^0$ limit of the $d\psi_n$ which are closed, thus is closed.

Comment: @Mindlack Actually, a much stronger result can be used here. $C^1\subset C^0$ but smooth forms are dense in $C^0$. So the closedness follows trivially by passing through the limit. $C^1$ is the part that bothers me significantly when I am interpreting the statement in relation to $d^2$ which drops the image below $C^0$. Once I knew it is distributional proof, I can see why the result makes sense.